# How is this javascript object destructuring working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, object-destructuring

I am trying to understand this React redux example on : https://codesandbox.io/s/f2ded

In **reducer.js**, the initial state is :

```
const initialState = {
  taskName: "",
  tasks: []
};
```

In **App.js**, we have :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    ...state.list
  };
};
```

The `state` does not have a property `list` and it `state.list` should be an empty object `{}`. But, it actually holds

Appreciate any help in understanding how exactly this works. Thank you.

Comment: This obviously isn't everything there is to the code.

Comment: Per the description, this shouldn't work. We need more information. Double check what you think you know about the behavior of the code.

Comment: There is no destructuring here. Do you mean the object spread?

Comment: The entire code is in the link.
Sorry, yes I meant object spread.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the combineReducers at the bottom

```
const reds = combineReducers({ list });

export default reds;
```

That means that everything in that part of the Redux state is `state.list.taskName` or `state.list.tasks` etc.

[edit] just wanted to add some clarity from the official docs, https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers/

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({potato: potatoReducer, tomato: tomatoReducer})
// This would produce the following state object
{
  potato: {
    // ... potatoes, and other state managed by the potatoReducer ...
  },
  tomato: {
    // ... tomatoes, and other state managed by the tomatoReducer, maybe some nice sauce? ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand it more deeply you need to learn about `combineReducers`

**Example**

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({potato: potatoReducer, tomato: tomatoReducer})
// This would produce the following state object
{
    potato: {
        // ... potatoes, and other state managed by the potatoReducer ...
    },
    tomato: {
        // ... tomatoes, and other state managed by the tomatoReducer, maybe some nice 
        // sauce? ...
    }
}
```

You can control state key names by using different keys for the reducers in the passed object. For example, you may call `combineReducers({ todos: myTodosReducer, counter: myCounterReducer })` for the state shape to be `{ todos, counter }`.

A popular convention is to name reducers after the state slices they manage, so you can use ES6 property shorthand notation: `combineReducers({ counter, todos })`. This is equivalent to writing `combineReducers({ counter: counter, todos: todos })`.

**So when you are using `...state.list` you are getting it because of `combineReducers({ list: listReducer })` or `simply combineReducers({ list})`**

To know more please follow: [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers/?_sm_au_=iVVfsm0RT6Brq3RHL321jK0f1JH33)